# Not able to create Hive table with TIMESTAMP datatype in Azure Databricks

Tags: pyspark, hive, parquet, azure-databricks

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Parquet does not support
> timestamp. See HIVE-6384;

Getting above error while executing following code in Azure Databricks.

```
spark_session.sql("""
                    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dev_db.processing_table
                    (
                      campaign STRING,
                      status STRING,
                      file_name STRING,
                      arrival_time TIMESTAMP
                    )
                    PARTITIONED BY ( 
                      Date DATE)
                    ROW FORMAT SERDE
                      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
                    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
                      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
                    OUTPUTFORMAT
                      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
                    LOCATION "/mnt/data_analysis/pre-processed/"
             """)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Hive-6384](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-6384) Jira, Starting from **Hive-1.2** you can use **`Timestamp,date`** types in parquet tables.

**Workarounds for Hive < 1.2 version:**

***1. Using String type:***

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dev_db.processing_table
                    (
                      campaign STRING,
                      status STRING,
                      file_name STRING,
                      arrival_time STRING
                    )
                    PARTITIONED BY ( 
                      Date STRING)
                   Stored as parquet
                   Location '/mnt/data_analysis/pre-processed/';
```

Then while processing you can cast `arrival_time`,`Date` cast to `timestamp`,`date` types.

Using a **`view`** and cast the columns but **`views are slow.`**

***`2. Using ORC format:`***

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dev_db.processing_table
                    (
                      campaign STRING,
                      status STRING,
                      file_name STRING,
                      arrival_time Timestamp
                    )
                    PARTITIONED BY ( 
                      Date date)
                   Stored as orc
                   Location '/mnt/data_analysis/pre-processed/';
```

ORC supports both `timestamp`,`date` type

Comment: do you have any idea, how to update hive metastore version in Azure Databricks

Comment: For anybody that showed up here as I did, here is the guidance from Azure on how to update the Hive metastore - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/metastore/parquet-timestamp-requires-msver12